# Scoping of function declarations within `with` statements

Tags: javascript, firefox, scope, with-statement

**Preface**: Use of `with` is [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) in JavaScript for good reason. It can lead to confusing code, and forward compatibility problems (when new properties are added to built-in objects, for example). This question isn't about whether or not `with` should be used - it's about the spec-defined behavior of `with`.

Should the following code work?

```
let foo = {};
with(foo) {
  function bar() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
bar();
```

It works in Chrome 80, but not in Firefox 72: `TypeError: bar is not a function`.

**Edit**: Turns out this error only occurs when pasting into the Firefox console (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4y5x.png), not when running the code within a HTML document.

But notice it's a `TypeError`, and not a `ReferenceError` (i.e. `bar is not defined`). To confirm this we can add `console.log("bar" in window)` before `bar();`, and notice that outputs true in Firefox, whereas if you write that before the code it outputs false. So in Firefox the above code has the effect of setting `window.bar` to `undefined`.

This works fine in both Firefox and Chrome:

```
if(true) {
  function bar() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
bar();
```

Just as I'd have expected, since a `function foo() {...}` declaration is function scoped. So unless there's something weird about `with` block scopes, it seems like this is a Firefox bug?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem with Firefox 73, so Firefox's behaviour may have changed.

That said, see [MDN on the subject of blocks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block):

> In strict mode, starting with ES2015, functions inside blocks are scoped to that block. Prior to ES2015, block-level functions were forbidden in strict mode.

IIRC, the interaction between hoisting rules and blocks was undefined which resulted in different behaviour in different JS engines. This isn't so much a Firefox bug as a bug in the definition of the language itself.

Avoid function declarations in blocks.

Comment: Thanks for testing that! I've just discovered that this bug only occurs when pasting into the console for some reason (on Firefox 72 and 73): https://i.imgur.com/WTG3iiX.png Works fine when it's in a HTML file. So it looks like it's just a Firefox console bug. (Just for reference, my actual use-case here is hacking JS to build a DSL, so I'm not actually trying to declare function-scoped functions within blocks in my day-to-day JS code.)